# List installed apps

Tags: windows-phone-7

There's absolutely no way to get the list of installed apps on a wp7 ? I mean via the development SDK. I'm writing an app that absolutely needs to have a simple list of installed apps.

Any hints are welcome,
Thanks in advance

Comment: Whilst it's true the capability isn't currently in the SDK, there's no reason you couldnt suggest this on their forums. Both answers point out it can't be done at the moment which is what you asked to confirm, so +1.

Comment: You're totally right indeed. I needed this feature urgently but well, even if I can't leverage it for this project I'll propose. Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The whole point of programming for Windows phone is that you work in a sandboxed environment, with no trust. So informations about the system, like the list of installed apps, are off limit for security reasons.

Comment: Even if the user allows the app to access these information ?

Comment: @MiloudB There's no way for the user to allow access to this information so it's a moot point.

Comment: Gotcha, that's unfortunate... Really unfortunate. And the *security* argument doesn't seem enough to me. Thank you guys

Comment: @Miloud Sandboxing is a security implementation. Not providing a list of installed apps via the SDK is more about prioritization of what functionality is made available and in what order. I can think of LOTS more things that should be introduced before this is added to the SDK.

Comment: I wouldn't want this information to be accessible to any apps even with explicit allowance by the user. Why? Just because the vast majority of users are not security-aware (they are barely computer-aware), and letting them make this kind of decisions would result in allowance 90+% of the time, even for an application without any obvious use of the information. A spyware developper's paradise.

Comment: @Falanwe If I follow your thinking, I'll conclude that users shouldn't be allowed to get a mobile device at all, even though, we let him get one, we let him get a computer... and many other complex stuff. Moreover, apps are basically distributed via the Marketplace which imply a prior anti-malware and fake apps testing. And having the list of installed apps doesn't present much risks imho... I sincerely envy Android developers regarding the OS openness :).

@Matt lacey Agreed. But well, I think if we're going to talk about what's missing, we will need a couple of hours hehe

Comment: If a user needs to do a reinstall, say to install memory, or they've gotten to the third R in generic troubleshooting (restart, reboot, reinstall) then being able to get a list of the apps you have downloaded (so you can go get them again) would be a pretty handy thing.  I'd PAY for an app that did that and then sent it to my e-mail or gave me some way to print it out or something.

Answer (score 2):

I dont think that's possible the sdk works as a sandbox

Comment: Should be a comment and not an answer

Comment: @Ardman It looks like an answer to me. It's speculative and could be better worded but I'd still classify it as an answer.